# Corona SDK. Lua: Centering image function

Tags: image, lua, coronasdk

I'm fairly new to Lua and Corona SDK but so far I'm finding everything very enjoyable. I've been following a tutorial to create a small mobile app game using Corona. It needed a lot of images to be centered so I decided to write the following function to center images.

```
local function centering(img)
    local centerX = display.contentcenterX
    local centerY = display.contentcenterY
    local img = img
    img.x = centerX; img.y = centerY
    return img
end

local obj1 = display.newImage("obj1.png")
local obj2 = display.newImage("obj2.png")
local obj3 = display.newImage("obj3.png")

local img_list = {obj1, obj2, obj3}
for i = 1, #img_list do
    centering(img_list[i])
end
```

Everything seems to compile without errors. However, the  images aren't in the center of the screen. What am I doing wrong? Any Lua or Corona SDK advice is gladly appreciated.

Comment: This is a typo, don't see any value in such question. Please delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentCenterX` and `contentCenterY` should be with capital letter C for center.

Comment: Thanks, without autocomplete it's quite hard to see some mistakes.